# How do you cast/type-juggle as an array in ruby?

Tags: php, ruby, arrays, casting

In PHP, I'm used to be able to type-juggle easily, for example, take any parameter and cast it as an array like so:

```
<?php

$foo = [1];
var_dump($foo);
// array(1) {
//   [0]=>
//   int(1)
// }

$foo = 1;
var_dump((array)$foo);
// array(1) {
//   [0]=>
//   int(1)
// }

$foo = "one";
var_dump((array)$foo);
// array(1) {
//   [0]=>
//   string(3) "one"
// }
```

What is a simple approximation of the same in Ruby? I feel like I am missing something extremely simple in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no equivalent. The closest thing would be to simply wrap a variable in an array:

```
x = "one"
p [x] # ["one"]
```

If you want to wrap something in an array *unless* it's already an array, use `Array()`:

```
x = "one"
p Array(x) # ["one"]

x = [1]
p Array(x) # [1], not [[1]]
```

Comment: So `x = Array("one")` is the same?

Comment: It's similar in use, but it's not "casting". It's just a shortcut for something like `x = (y.is_a? Array ? y : [y])`